# How can we move a worker (a resource) to the overhead crane trolley location and seize it before overhead crane start moving?

Tags: anylogic

The problem is that the overhead crane is not a resource, network node and I cant place attractor on it so I cant use resourceSendTo block. also I cant for example seize worker before moveByCrane block because its not an agent. is there any way to do that?